# Hibernate Tools - disable entity class generator for composite primary keys in table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-tools

Is it possible, with Hibernate Tools, to generate POJO files avoiding the generation of entity classes on tables with composite primary keys?

I have this table with composite key:

```
CREATE TABLE `arc_test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`data`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>  
    <table name="arc_test" catalog="db">
        <primary-key>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </primary-key>       
    </table> 
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Hibernate Tools generated this two class:

```
public class ArcTest implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private ArcTestId   id;
    private String      text;
    .....
    .....

public class ArcTestId implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private Integer id;
    private Date    data;
        .....
        .....
```

but I would like only one class like this:

```
   public class ArcTest implements java.io.Serializable
    {
        private Integer id;
        private Date    data;
        private String  text;
        .....
        .....
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Like I told you on [Discourse](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/hibernate-tools-is-it-possible-ignore-composite-id-in-table/6748), it's not yet possible, but you can create a JIRA issue for this.

Comment: I have checked and currently Hibernate Tools does not allow this